# In the pivot table, how can I change the column attribute being displayed.?

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

Instead of the "Count of Category" I want the "Names of the Category" generated by the pivot table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the PivotTable Fields area, drag the field you want into the columns section. Then, click on the small arrow that would appear for that datatype. Go to Field Settings and from the Subtotals section, you'll find many choices to represent the data. Select the type of data representation you need